# Интерполяция по кривым Безье c отрицательными параметрами

Tags: css3, svg, анимация, transition, интерполяция

Как устроена интерполяция transition при использовании кривых безье? Что происходит, если указанная кривая Безье выходит на пределы интерполируемого отрезка?

[image: кривая безье]

```css
section {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

div {
  height: 4em;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 10s cubic-bezier(0,2,.5,-2);
}

.width {
  background: silver;
}

section:hover .width {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 10px solid blue;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

section:hover .left {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="width"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: ну вроде как тут видно что t = y, даже за пределами интервала 0-1

Answer (score 2):

Немного теории, чтобы понять влияние Кубической кривой Безье на режимы ускорений анимации.

Ниже рисунок, поясняющий параметры кубической кривой Безье:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код кривой Безье, для получения формы кривой, как на рисунке выше
[тут](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=907) подробнее о кубических кривых Безье

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 600" >  
<path d="M 200,300 C 100,100  500,100  400,300" 
      style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:4; fill:none;"/>
</svg>
```

В CSS правилах `cubic-bezier()` для унификации отброшены координаты начальной и финальной точек кривой.  Они по умолчанию равны 0,0  1,1

Оставлены только координаты **x1,y1 x2, y2** -  рычагов, управляющих формой кривой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Генератор кубической кривой](https://cubic-bezier.com/#.01,.63,.97,.04) от Леа Вероу

Шкала абцисс (горизонтальная)  здесь это время в долях от  0 до 1 или 0%-100%
Шкала ординат (вертикальная) - это прогрессивная шкала, которая наглядно показывает с каким ускорением должен протекать процесс.

### linear

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из рисунка видим прямо пропорциональную зависимость прогресса выполнения анимации, например перемещения на `300px`. За половину времени, будут пройдено половина пути.

Ниже пример linear:

```css
.box {
  background: crimson;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.linear .box {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);
}

#go:target .box {
  -webkit-transform: translate(300px);
  transform: translate(300px);
}

body {
  font: .7em Arial;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
}

a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="go">

        <a href="#go">Animate</a> <a href="#reset">Reset</a>
        <div class="linear">
            <h2>Linear</h2>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

## ease-in-out

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По графику видим, что начало и конец анимации идёт медленно (пологая часть), середина пролетает быстро. Вывод, чем круче наклон кривой, тем быстрее. Более пологая кривая обуславливает более медленное течение анимации.

Ниже демонстрирующий это код:

```css
.box {
  background: crimson;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.linear .box {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);
}

.ease-in-out .box {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1);
}

#go:target .box {
  -webkit-transform: translate(300px);
  transform: translate(300px);
}

body {
  font: .7em Arial;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
}

a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="go">

        <a href="#go">Animate</a> <a href="#reset">Reset</a>

        <p>Все приведенные ниже анимации длятся ровно 2 секунды.</p>

        <div class="ease-in-out">
            <h2>ease-in-out</h2>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="linear">
            <h2>Linear</h2>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

## Ответ на вопрос

> **Что происходит, если указанная кривая Безье выходит на пределы интерполируемого отрезка?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.box {
  background: crimson;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 4s;
  transition-duration: 4s;
}

.linear .box {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);
}

.ease .box {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2,.52,.51,-2);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2,.52,.51,-2);
}

#go:target .box {
  -webkit-transform: translate(300px);
  transform: translate(300px);
}

body {
  font: .7em Arial;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
}

a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="go">

        <a href="#go">Animate</a> <a href="#reset">Reset</a>

        <p>Все приведенные ниже анимации длятся ровно 2 секунды.</p>

        <div class="ease">
            <h2>cubic-bezier(.2,.52,.51,-2)</h2>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="linear">
            <h2>Linear</h2>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Короткий ответ:

При отрицательных значениях параметров `cubic-bezier(.2,.52,.51,-2)` происходит возврат анимированного объекта назад. Если было задано перемещение объекта вперед на `0-300px`то будет возврат в отрицательную область.

Из-за чего это происходит? Смотрите работу кода выше. Время для обоих анимаций одинаково, но при значениях оси ординат (**y**) больше `1` в абсолютных значениях величина шкалы прогресса становится больше единицы. Вот эта разница уходит на движение в обратную сторону.

На финиш обе анимации -linear и анимация с отрицательными значениями `cubic-bezier` приходят в одно время, время указанное в продолжительности анимации.

Comment: Но не все параметры могут становиться отрицательными - например, ширина.

Comment: @Qwertiy а при чем тут ширина :) Речь же идет об отрицательных значениях cubic-bezier /  Ну если анимируется ширина, то наверное просто уйдет в ноль. Надо попробовать

Answer (score 1):

Как комментировал **@Qwertiy♦:**

> Но не все параметры могут становиться отрицательными - например,
> ширина

***Смотрите на полный экран, иначе не увидите всю картину анимации***

```css
.box {
  background: crimson;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 4s;
  transition-duration: 4s;
  margin-left:300px;
}

.linear .box {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);
}

.ease .box {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2,.52,.51,-2);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2,.52,.51,-2);
}

#go:target .box {
    width:300px;
}

body {
  font: .7em Arial;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
}

a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="go">

        <a href="#go">Animate</a> <a href="#reset">Reset</a>

        <p>Все приведенные ниже анимации длятся ровно 4 секунды.</p>

        <div class="ease">
            <h2>cubic-bezier(.2,.52,.51,-2)</h2>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="linear">
            <h2>Linear</h2>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Действительно, как я и предполагал при анимации **width** и отрицательных значениях **cubic-bezier(.2,.52,.51,-2)** ширина уходит в ноль на отрицательном значении прогрессирующей шкалы, а затем анимация возвращается в положительном направлении и обе анимации заканчиваются одновременно в одном месте.

Comment: А в стандарте-то это есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy как мы и говорили с вами год назад, в стандарте W3C не рекомендуется делать отрицательные значения cubic-bezier. Но все современные браузеры поддерживают отрицательные значения и обрабатывают их одинаково, даже Microsoft Edge